# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value - Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have got stored proc which checks if a date is not on a working day and changes it if nessecary. I am calling this proc in visual studio like below. However when the proc is run i receive `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value` message. When i run the same proc in SQL Server Management Studio with the same values used in visual studio it works.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PSTN_GetWorkingDay]

    @TargetDate VARCHAR(30)

AS  

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /* Workout 10 working days from present date */
    DECLARE @MaxDateCantBook DATETIME

    ;WITH DatesCTE AS
    (
        SELECT Date_Id,
               Date_Date,
               Date_JDE,
               Is_WorkingDay,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date_Date) AS rn
        FROM   dbo.Dates
        WHERE  Is_WorkingDay = 1
               AND Date_Date > GETDATE()
    )

    SELECT @MaxDateCantBook = (SELECT Date_Date FROM DatesCTE WHERE rn = 10)                                      

    /* Change Target date if it is less than 10 working days in the future */
    IF(@TargetDate <= @MaxDateCantBook)
    BEGIN

        SET @TargetDate = @MaxDateCantBook
    END


    SELECT Date_Date
    FROM dbo.Dates
    WHERE Date_Date >= @TargetDate
    AND Date_Date <= (SELECT MIN(Date_Date) 
                        FROM dbo.Dates 
                        WHERE Is_WorkingDay != 0 AND Date_Date >= @TargetDate)
    ORDER BY Date_Date DESC


END
```

I'm setting the parameters for the query like below:

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
              {
                  new SqlParameter("TargetDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30){ Value = input.date}
              };
```

Where `input.date` is a string = 2014-09-30

Comment: I guess your `input.date` contain date value in this format - **"30/09/2014(dd/mm/yyyy)"**. But it is better to pass date in sql standard format that is - **"yyyy-mm-dd"**. This might resolve your problem.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, **yyyy-mm-dd is not sql standard!** `2014-10-01` becomes january 10th in europe. Use **yyyymmdd**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `@TargetDate VARCHAR(30)` to `@TargetDate DATETIME` in your SP.

when you set the parameter you can do as below

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetDate",
         DateTime.ParseExact(input.date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

or

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
              {
                  new SqlParameter("@TargetDate", SqlDbType.DateTime){ Value = DateTime.ParseExact(input.date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}
              };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i do as you suggested i get `Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.` and the input parameter is now `30/09/2014 00:00:00`

Comment: Apologies fixed the above issue and all seems to be wrking now. It was the Datatype of the input.date needed changing to a DateTime